# C# ASP Dot Net 4.5 prepared statements with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

My Class CRUD has the following method:

```
 public bool dbQuery(string sql,string[] paramList= null)
{
    bool flag = false;
    try
    {
        connect();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,con);
        cmd.Prepare();
        if(paramList != null)
        {
         foreach(string i in paramList){
                string[] valus = i.Split(',');
                string p = valus[0];
                string v = valus[1];
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p,v);
            }
         }
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        this.error(exc);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            closeCon();
        }
        catch (Exception excf)
        {
            this.error(excf);
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I am sending query like the following ways:

```
 string sql = "SELECT * FROM dept_login WHERE (user_email = ?user_email OR user_cell = ?user_cell ) AND userkey = ?userkey";
    string[] param = new string[] {
         "\"?user_email\",\""+ userid.Text.ToString()+"\"" ,
         "\"?user_cell\",\""+ userid.Text.ToString()+"\"" ,
         "\"?userkey\",\""+ userkey.Text.ToString()+"\""
    };
    
    if (db.dbQuery(sql, param))
    {
        msg.Text = "Ok";
    }
    else
    {
        msg.Text = "<strong class='text-danger'>Authentication Failed</strong>";
    }
```

But it says the

```
Parameter "?user_email" must be defined"
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any best way to use it with parameters to search, insert, update and or delete record in MySQL database. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Dot Net Framework 4.5 on windows 10 with 64-bit, MySQL Server 5.6.21.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass this value to your `dbQuery()` method:

```
"\"?user_email\",\""+ userid.Text.ToString()+"\""
```

It ends up passing something like this to `AddWithValue()`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("\"?user_email\"", "\"123\"");
```

Remove the escaped quotes and try again.

```
string[] param = new string[] {
    string.Format("{0},{1}", "?user_email", userid.Text),
    string.Format("{0},{1}", "?user_cell", userid.Text),
    string.Format("{0},{1}", "?userkey", userkey.Text)
};
```

Comment: Dear @Grant Winney I have done as you suggest but now it says that " Parameter "?user_email" not found in the collection" ?

Comment: string[] param = new string[] {
             "?user_email,"+ userid.Text.ToString(),
             "?user_cell,"+ userid.Text.ToString(),
             "?userkey,"+ userkey.Text.ToString()
        };   Working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my defeined array to the following:

```
 string[] param = new string[] {
         "?user_email,"+ userid.Text.ToString(),
         "?user_cell,"+ userid.Text.ToString(),
         "?userkey,"+ userkey.Text.ToString()
    };
```

The Answer of @Grant Winney is correct but commas he defined outside the string param... Any ways thanks @Grant Winney